# jQuery css selectors - select all but last a

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

Here is my html:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Guestbook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a id="cart" href="#"><span class="glyph general">2</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

and i want to create jQuery hover effect on all but last anchors with purple background and the last child with id="cart" red background and here is my jquery:

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $("nav ul li a:not(#cart)").hover(
            function (){
                $(this).hide().css("background-color","#6e0069").fadeIn(500);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).css("background-color","rgb(255,255,255)");
            }
        );
})
```

how to add same function but for the last element with red background?

Comment: You can't target links that have been visited with JavaScript: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: i dont want to target visited link

Comment: Anchors with a purple background are visited links.

Comment: No, he wants to *give* a purple background with `hover()`, not *access* those elements *with* a purple background. And `:visited` links tend to have purple `color` not `background-color`.

Comment: nope i just want to style my hover with purple and red background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but I would do something like this:

```
$("nav ul li a").hover(function() {
    var color = $(this).is("#cart") ? "rgb(255,0,0)" : "#6e0069"
    $(this).hide().css("background-color", color).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255,255,255)");
});​
```

Comment: That's so much tidier than my multiple-`hover()` first-thougth. +1!